# How to clear out a drawn texture from the screen in java libGDX Framework

Tags: libgdx

I am using the java libGDX Framework for game development.I am trying to clear out the drawn texture from the screen.

Lets take a classic game example - in many games when the character goes through the coins the coins clears out from the screen and displays a sweet animation like fade in and fade out the points collected from that coin(+10) and show the coin exploding animation on that position.

I want to do something similar to that.
I am using `SpriteBatch` to draw the texture region like below.

**Setting texture Region:**

```
   (...)
    public Texture texture;
    public TextureRegion coin;
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest); 
    coin = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 336, 65, 73);
   (...)
```

**Drawing the texture into screen :**

```
  public SpriteBatch batcher;
  batcher = new SpriteBatch();
  batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
  batcher.begin();
  batcher.enableBlending();
  batcher.draw(coin, x, y, 65,73);
  (...)
  (...)
  batcher.end();
```

The game character is also drawn using the same logic shown above.
Now when the game character will collide with the coin that I have drawn,the coin must be cleared(vanished) and some animation or big font like +50 must fadein and fadeout in that position.I tried but didn't find anything that would do this.
So how to do that ?

Comment: libgdx is not one for having simple easy one line ways if doing things. You'll have to do everything yourself

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 I am not asking for the whole game code . I just wanted to know if there is some function to undraw/delete/remove the texture which I have drawn using spritebatch .

Comment: How are your coins stored?

Comment: The texture.png has a coin image and other game asset images. I get the coin image from there using TextureRegion() as i have shown in the code itself .

Comment: That's good, but how do you store the (x, y) coordinates of the coin?

Comment: you can keep anything on that x and y . As of now I have just taken x and y manually say x = 200 and y = 300 .

Answer (score 1):

Libgdx has Stage/Actor for draw/hide/move  etc... (com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d).

Create actor with texture:
`Image image = new Image(yourTexture);`
`stage.addActor(image);`

In render:
`stage.draw()`

Stop drawing texture:
`image.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Removing just means not drawing, so stop calling `batcher.draw(coin, x, y, 65,73);`. Of course you probably have lots of coins so putting a bunch of draw calls in `if` statements is going to get messy. Put all your coin locations in a List or array. Loop through the list of coin locations when drawing and just remove taken coins from the collection. To fade out you want to mess with the alpha for your batch for each coin `batcher.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha);`

You can make up your own math to calculate how the alpha changes while your coin is fading or you can look into using the com.badlogic.gdx.math.Interpolation class or the Universal Tween Engine.

It'll be easier to manage this if you switch over to using Sprites.

```
// not in render
Sprite coin1 = new Sprite(coinTextureRegion);
coin1.setPosition(x,y);

// in render
coin1.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha); // if fading
coin1.draw(batch);
```

Comment: Can you give a small example of doing it with sprites then  ?